# Build failed: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: Unknown service account showing up in error message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud-function

`Build failed: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 909263763911@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 909263763911@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1665066353404;unknown;ResFormat=AUTOMATIC;ServerTimeSec=0.046704348;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=AUTOMATIC;ReqID=17f5636ce15f4efa;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a65:f1ea:0:b0:46:3bbe:5444]:4001`

**However when I run "gcloud iam service-accounts list" , I dont see the specified account. I do see an account that looks similar but the email was different. Am I doing something wrong?**

`gcloud iam service-accounts list

DISPLAY NAME                            EMAIL                                                        DISABLED
firebase-adminsdk                       firebase-adminsdk-80bfr@algo-321412.iam.gserviceaccount.com  False
dbconnector                             dbconnector@algo-321412.iam.gserviceaccount.com              False
Compute Engine default service account  909263763911-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com           False
gmailsenderAlgo                         gmailsenderalgo@algo-321412.iam.gserviceaccount.com          False
App Engine default service account      algo-321412@appspot.gserviceaccount.com                      False`

Comment: That account is not in the service account section. look it at IAM and grant the needed permissions

Comment: Yeah, I cannot find it in service account section. I dont remember using cloud build as well, So I'm unsure as to how it got there

Answer (score 0):

The command `gcloud iam service-accounts list` list all the service account of your current project. Those service accounts have this pattern `<custom name that you provide>@<projectID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. The projectID is `algo-321412` in your case

This time, the service account has a different format `909263763911@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`. It doesn't belong to your project, but to Cloud Build service. The prefix `909263763911` is your project number. This service account is named "Cloud Build default service account"

When you run a Cloud Build job, and if you don't mention any [custom service account to use](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts), the Cloud Build default service account is used and all the default Cloud API call (through GCLOUD or through piece of custom code) use this service account.

In your case, you have some missing permission on that default service account. Grant the required permissions (copy the service account and add the correct role at the correct level of the resource). Or use a custom service account, with the correct permission and use it in Cloud Build jobs.